# jquery SlideToggle effect in upward direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I need to make a jquery slidetoggle effect in upward direction., now the slide toggle is working only in downward direction. When i used slide up method i couldn't use same button to slide up and slide down the div.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11/jquery.min.js">              </script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#flip").click(function(){
  $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");



 });
});
</script>

<style> 
#panel,#flip
{

padding:5px;
text-align:center;
height:92px;
width:261px;
opacity:0.8;
background-color:#b3171d;
```

}

```
 #panel
{
padding:50px;
background:url(maharani%20html/images/prince.jpg) no-repeat;
width:262px;
height:248px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="flip">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

I am a beginner in jquery., please help me  :)

Comment: You can use animate in jquery

Comment: @ShuhaibV , give me code dude, i tried, but didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code Here is **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tg2rupcg/5/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">                 </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#flip").click(function(){
      $("#panel").slideToggle({
      direction: "up"
    }, 400);

 });
});
</script>
<style> 
#panel,#flip
{

position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom:2%;
  z-index: 100;
opacity:0.8;
background-color:#b3171d;
}
 #panel
{
    display: none;
padding:50px;
background:url(maharani%20html/images/prince.jpg) no-repeat;
width:262px;
height:248px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
    </div>
    <div id="flip">Click to slide up panel</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MasreMohsin,  thanks for your post., But i want to make the button constant(static), and need to slide the paragraph from button up and down(toggle). thanx

Comment: I have updated the code, just go through the JSFiddle provided.

Comment: Dude, this is the effect that i already have. see , this sliding effect is in downward direction. when clicking on panel div, sliding goes downward. i want it to be in upward direction, thanks for your time.pls help me out

Comment: Now check out, slideToggle in upward direction!

Comment: JSFiddle also, showing the output we already have. we need to make the direction to be opposit.